# Drawing aligned strings by formatting double values

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I am creating a user control which creates a table of a double array.
I am able to draw them but I don't know how align the values.

Example: my data looks like

```
 double[] data = new double[]
            {
                -13.5,
                -8.5,
                -3.5,
                0,
                3.5,
                8.5,
                13.5
            };
```

so i want that when i draw these values they should be aligned (right aligned) so the dot appears exactly on same place for all values.

Here is the code I am using:

```
private void DrawTable()
        {
            _format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            _format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;
            int yPos = 2;
            RectangleF rect = RectangleF.Empty;
            foreach (var item in Data)
            {
                string str = item.ToString("F3");
                str = string.Format("{0}dB", str);
                str = string.Format("{0,10}",str);
                SizeF size = _gBmp.MeasureString(str, Font);
                rect.X = 5;
                rect.Y = yPos;
                rect.Width = size.Width;
                rect.Height = size.Height;
                _gBmp.DrawString(str, Font, _textBrush, rect, _format);
                yPos += 20;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Okay? What is your question? What's wrong with the code you have right now?

Comment: @tnw the text is not aligned, means -13.500 and 3.500 is not aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are drawing each item in a rectangle which you create by measuring the size of the string.

You instead need to use the same width rectangle for each string you draw.  Then if you right-align the strings they will line up (provided you're using the same font).

Do not use the `String.Format` padding to pad the strings for you.  It's not the right way to do it with GDI+ and it's mainly for fixed-width fonts like a console display.  The only thing you want to use string formatting for is to specify a fixed number of decimal places.

If I want the width of the column to be dynamically sized normally what I do is measure every element in the list and then select the maximum width of all of the measured widths.  Usually you want to clamp it to a max width in case you have a really long string, though.

Answer (score 0):

use `PadLeft()` method of string object. all you need now is to string format the numbers to equal decimals for that find the max char after decimal point then find biggest integer and total up the characters with the decimal point and just `PadLeft()`a space with the max characters you just calculated

Answer (score -1):

wouldnt a `GridView` have sufficed..?? a right aligned column for integral part, a left aligned column for decimal part. hide the cell borders, readonly/disable the whole grid...